# Changing alternate icon on iPhone and iPad (setAlternateIcon for iPhone & iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, icons

I've implemented this code (and added the CFBundleAlternateIcons correctly in the Info.plist):

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("MyCustomIcon") { error in
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
} else {
    print("Finished")
}}
```

If I run this on the iPhone everything works fine, but on iPad the error message 'The file doesn’t exist.' shows up.
Is there a way to implement all sizes of icons?
Or do I have to add a separate item to the Info.plist?

Answer (score 2):

Same here, I had to define both the     CFBundleIcons
and     CFBundleIcons~ipad
with the same settings to get it working on iPad too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: not working for me please post your plist code or take screenshot of it

Comment: See screenshots above